# Rename local file before upload to FTP in Windows command-line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp, rename

I have the following script which does not work for some reason.
I need to rename (appending current date) `Feed.txt` file every day and upload it to FTP. What am I missing?

```
eco
secret_pwd
ascii
lcd C:\Jobs
rename Feed*.txt Feed_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
cd Uploads
put Feed_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%.txt
quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`rename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-rename)
 in `ftp.exe` script renames a file on FTP server.

While you want to rename a local file. For that you need to use [`rename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rename) command of `cmd.exe`, not `ftp.exe`.

So either move the `rename` to a batch file that executes your FTP script, if any.

Or prefix the `rename` with [`!`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/ff687695(v%3dws.11)) to instruct `ftp.exe` to escape to `cmd.exe`.